# Same keyboard key to act as a shortcut for two opposite actions

Tags: c++, qt, shortcut

I am using C++/Qt 5.5 and in my software, I want the Qt::Key_Space to trigger the opening of a menu, and the same button, to trigger the closing of the **same** menu. The problem is that if I implement it as:

```
this->button = new QPushButton();
this->button->setShortcut( QKeySequence( Qt::Key_Space ) );
connect(this->button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MenuClass::startMenuButtonClicked);
```

...

```
    this->in_menu_button = new QPushButton();
    this->in_menu_button->setShortcut( QKeySequence( Qt::Key_Space ) );
    connect(this->in_menu_button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &InTheMenuClass::startMenuButtonClicked);
```

If i do it like this, only one way to the menu works. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create only one button and assign the shortcut to it. Then depending on the state of the menu (open/close) perform an opposite action in the button's handler.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your answer? I didn't quite get it

Comment: In your case you creat etwo instances of the QPushButton. In my proposal I ment you don't need to create the second button, but just use one, because only one may have the same schortcut in the active window. Then in the handler of this single button you just read the state of the menu (or either you use a state variable) and then rename the button (optionally) and close the menu if it was open or opened it if it was closed. Something like that, a kind of a state machine.

Comment: it is not possible to use the same QPushButton because it's styling is completely different when it's in the menu.

Comment: @gelazari thats kinda confusing, because your question says you want to use the "same button" for both action while your code creates two buttons...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a state machine. I created an enumaration with 2 states and made a static instance of it.

```
public:
    enum STATE {MAIN_WINDOW, MENU};
    static STATE state;
```

Then, i initialized it by default to have the MAIN_WINDOW state.

```
MyClass::STATE MyClass::state = STATE::MAIN_WINDOW;
```

Then, I connected both slots of the shortcuts for both buttons to call the same slot which checks and sets the current state.

```
QShortcut * shortcut = new QShortcut( QKeySequence( Qt::Key_Space ), back_to_main );
connect( shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, this, &MyClass::checkState);

QShortcut * shortcut = new QShortcut( QKeySequence( Qt::Key_Space ), go_to_menu );
connect( shortcut, &QShortcut::activated, this, &MyClass::checkState);

void MyClass::checkState()
{
    if (MyClass::state == MyClass::MAIN_WINDOW )
    {
        MyClass::goToMenu();
        MyClass::state = MyClass::STATE::MENU;
    }
    else if ( MyClass::state == MyClass::MENU )
    {
        MyClass::goBackToMain();
        MyClass::state = MyClass::STATE::MAIN_APP;
    }
}
```

*MyClass can be any class.